# Quorum cakeshop - Error while starting up

Tags: quorum

I hava a question regarding Quorum cakeshop.

Currently I am trying to get the cakeshop running, what i want to use to play a around with Quorum a little. More infos below:
https://github.com/jpmorganchase/cakeshop/blob/master/README.md

I followed the Quickstart instructions via Spring Boot but I am running in an error (OS=Windows10).

The manual tells me to run this command "java -jar cakeshop.war".
While doing this I get a bunch of Errors from the filemanager coming from a java FileNotFoundException. Anyone has the same kind of problem or any ideas of how to solve this problem?

Also does anybody know if there is a place where I can ask specific Quorum questions?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when running in Windows, -Dgeth.node=geth must be specified as Quorum is not yet available on Windows OS

Hope you did the same for it.